# How to load a font.ttf inside the project

Tags: java, fonts, jar

this is my problem: I'm trying to load a font that is saved inside my project but I dont know how to do it... This is what i have tryed:

```
    private void registerFont(){

    GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
    try{
        ge.registerFont(Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT,new File(classLoader.getResource("net/utils/ttf/Press Style Extra L.ttf").getFile())));
    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

this is the error:

[Client thread/INFO]: [STDERR]: java.io.IOException: Can't read D:\Client\Client\eclipse\out\production\Client\net\utils\ttf\Press%20Style%20Extra%20L.ttf
[Client thread/INFO]: [STDERR]:     at java.awt.Font.createFont(Font.java:1054)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem in your code is this part:

```
classLoader.getResource("net/utils/ttf/Press Style Extra L.ttf").getFile()
```

To be precise .getFile()

- The getResource() returns an URL to the resource from the classpath.
- Consider that in case you will put your font inside the jar file, the path is not the same as the path in the filesystem (it point's so something inside the jar)
- Url.getFile() does not return a file path, but the file part of the URL ( https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#getFile() )

If you are using classLoader.getResource() that means for me that you are trying to get a file from your application classpath. In that case, it's probably added somewhere to your resources or resources tree. In that case there's no need for taking "file path", but just use a stream directly.

This code works for me:

```
        final ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
        try (InputStream stream = loader.getResourceAsStream("Roboto-Thin.ttf")) {
            Font font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, stream);
            System.out.println("Font: " + font);
        } catch (FontFormatException | IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(FontLoader.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

Hints:

- I'm using classloader from the current thread (it's good practice in case of dynamic environments, I don't know if this is your case)
- I'm opening stream rather than obtaining a file name
- The font is inside of the jar file

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
    final Font font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("some_font.ttf"))).deriveFont(Font.PLAIN, 18);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.